# How can i wakeup a sleeping external drive

Tags: vb.net

I need to get a sleeping external drive awake.
I tried:

```
IO.File.Create(USBDrive & "\$$$.$$$", 8, IO.FileOptions.WriteThrough).Dispose()
IO.File.Delete(USBDrive & "\$$$.$$$")
```

This works most of the time but not always.

Comment: Why do you need this? Normally this should not be necessary.

Comment: I need this because many external drives go into sleep mode after 10 minutes. It may be a problem if the external drive was plugged in a while before the program being started. (It must keep a back-up if its data)